# There is a problem with Elasticsearch paging searches

Tags: java, elasticsearch, search, paging, elk

I am trying to paging with Elasticsearch, but the following problem occurs.

1. From and Size cannot exceed max_result_window size.
2. Problem of slow search due to too many iterations of Scroll Search or Search After

Thanks to everyone who replies.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show your code first, also describe your problem better. Why do you need to iterate whatever? Just set different from parameter

Comment: When searching all logs of a user named "jobs" in an index named "user log", repeated search is required to search deep data. This is because the user wants to see all logs with one filter called "Jobs".

Comment: then just use scroll serach and read about pagination in elasticsearch with scroll (it uses something called scroll_id) Don't fetch 10 items just fetch all 10000 (it's default max you can change it in elastic settings) and after each fetch just use scroll_id to fetch next page

Comment: Why would you need to discard all the data you've retrieved already? Logs in the past don't change, why retrieving them again when going to the previous page, just cache them. It's not an ES problem, it's a UI problem :-)